# Javascript inheritance is not working

Tags: javascript

Facing inheritance problem in this below code i am new to OOPS concepts please help me.

```
var testA = function() {
  this._data = undefined
};
testA.prototype.init = function(data) {
  this._data = data;
};
testA.prototype.get = function(data) {
  if (this._data) {
    return data
  }
};
var testB = function() {}
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA);
var instance = new testB();
testB.prototype.init = function(data) {
  testA.prototype.init.call(this, data);
};
testB.prototype.Somedata = function() {
  testA.prototype.get();
}
instance.init("testdata");
instance.Somedata() // here i am getting this._data is undefined
```

1. When i call instance.init("testdata") now it's setting value to this._data in the parent.
2. When i call instance.Somedata() here i am getting undefined

May i know what could be reason? and how can i get the this._data value when i call instance.Somedata().

Comment: You just changed your code? The problem was `testA.init` not existing, now you've edited away the error.

Comment: yes just now i edited it

Comment: may i know how i can get the this._data value when i call instance.somedata()

Answer (score 0):

At first:

```
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA);
```

Instantiates a function, you may want to either instantiate the prototype:

```
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA.prototype);
```

or construct it directly:

```
testB.prototype =new testA;
```

Secondly SomeData is not returning anything, may do so and you also need to keep the context:

```
testB.prototype.Somedata = function() {
  return testA.prototype.get.call(this,"return");
}
```

Or even easier if we did the upper inheritance right:

```
testB.prototype.Somedata = function() {
  return this.get("return");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response let me try it out

Comment: It's working but why do we need to use call alwasy? if we have already data is set?

Answer (score 0):

Your using Object.create against a constructor, you should use it against an instance, otherwise, you get a function in return instead of an object.

```
var TestA = function() {
    this._data = undefined;
};
TestA.prototype.init = function(data) {
    this._data = data;
};
TestA.prototype.get = function() {
    return this._data;
};

var instance = Object.create(new TestA());
instance.init('some');
instance.get();
```

Comment: Still it's not working i am getting this._data is undefined when i call instance.get()

Comment: Not sure, I just copied this code into the console, and it's working fine. Can you show me your latest code?